# Decrease run time of this java program

Tags: java, arrays

I have made a program to input an array, and find the product of 3 largest numbers of the array such that:

The array constitutes of sub-arrays consisting of index increased one at a time.

That is, for an array of 10 elements, find the product considering the first 3 elements, then first 4 elements, then first 5 elements and so on.

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class monkmulti {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());    // no. of elements
        String xs = br.readLine(); //accepting those elements in a string
        xs=xs+" ";
        if(n<1||n>100000)  //constraint
            System.exit(0);
        int i,temp,count=0;
        for(i=0;i<xs.length();i++)
        {
            if(xs.charAt(i)==' ')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count!=n)    //checks if no. of elements are equal to n
            System.exit(0);
        int[] x=new int[count];
        int k=0;
        temp=0;
        for(i=0;i<xs.length();i++)
        {
            if(xs.charAt(i)==' ')
            {
                x[k++]=Integer.parseInt(xs.substring(temp, i));
                temp=i+1;
            }
        }
        count=0;
        int len=x.length,j;
        int[] x1=new int[len];
        System.arraycopy(x, 0, x1, 0, len);
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(x[i]<1||x[i]>100000)      //constraint for each element
                System.exit(0);
        }
        int m1=0,m2=0,m3=0;
        int max1=x[0],max2=x[0],max3=x[0];
        /*code to be improved below from here*/
        for(i=2;i<len;i++)            
        {
            for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
            {
                for(k=0;k<i;k++)
                {
                    if(x1[k]>x1[k+1])
                    {
                        temp=x1[k];
                        x1[k]=x1[k+1];
                        x1[k+1]=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(x1[i]*x1[i-1]*x1[i-2]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Input:**

n=user inputs no. of elements in array
xs= string accepting n elements separated by a space

**Output:**

product considering first 3 elements
product considering first 4 elements
so on..

**Example:**

**Input:**
5
6 2 9 3 8

**Output:**
-1
-1
108
162
432

**Explanation**
There are 5 integers 6,2,9,3,8
For the third index, the top 3 numbers are 6,2 and 9 whose product is 108.
For the fourth index, the top 3 numbers are 6,9 and 3 whose product is 162.
For the fifth index, the top 3 numbers are 6,9 and 8 whose product is 432.

Comment: What do you mean with the output of first X elements? The first sentence mean product of the largest three elements``. I'm confused.

Comment: @Konrad - i added a test case for better understanding

Comment: What happens if the array is unsorted?

Is the goal just to find the largest possible product of 3 numbers? Or do you want the product of the first 3, then the next 3, then the next 3 elements in the array and so on and so on.

Comment: The array may or may not be sorted, that's upto the user. The goal is to find the product of 3 largest numbers of smaller arrays of sizes 3[0...2], 4[0...3], 5[0...4] and so on and print the product everytime.

Comment: Your explanation in that comment is different from the example you gave above. 

I can post a solution which gives the output you wanted in the original question.

Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No the explanation in comment is not different.

Comment: Ok, you want:
 - the product of the three largest numbers
 - from all sub arrays with size 3..n starting at index 0  (range of n is 1...100000; range should start with 3!)
 - of an array containing unsorted numbers
Is this right?

Comment: @Konrad - Ok, I updated the example for a better understanding of the problem

Comment: @kamal0808 Edited, I can't improve it more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, You need something like this:

The order is O(items * log(subgroups)) -> O(items * log(3)) -> O(items)

```
public static void product(int[] items, int subGroup) {
    if (subGroup > 0 && items.length >= subGroup) {
        // this save the largest numbers:
        PriorityQueue<Integer> maxElements = new PriorityQueue<>(subGroup);
        int product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            // the queue of largest numbers is full:
            if (maxElements.size() == subGroup) {
                // the minimum of previous largest number is lower than the new number
                if (maxElements.peek() < items[i]) {
                    // swapping
                    product /= maxElements.poll();
                    product *= items[i];
                    maxElements.add(items[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(product);
            } else {
                product *= items[i];
                maxElements.add(items[i]);
                if (maxElements.size() < subGroup) {
                    //the queue of largest numbers isn't full
                    System.out.println("-1");
                } else {
                    // the queue of largest numbers is full now
                    System.out.println(product);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = {6, 2, 9, 3, 8};
    product(input, 3);
}
```

Output:

```
-1
-1
108
162
432
```

EDIT:
A little bit faster:

```
private static void heap(int[] maxElements) {
    int candidate = 1;
    if (maxElements[1] > maxElements[2]) {
        candidate = 2;
    }
    if (maxElements[0] > maxElements[candidate]) {
        int temp = maxElements[0];
        maxElements[0] = maxElements[candidate];
        maxElements[candidate] = temp;
    }
}

private static int addElement(int k, int[] maxElements, int item) {
    if (k < 3) {
        maxElements[k++] = item;
        if (k < 3) {
            System.out.println("-1");
        } else {
            heap(maxElements);
            System.out.println(maxElements[0] * maxElements[1] * maxElements[2]);
        }
    } else {
        if (maxElements[0] < item) {
            maxElements[0] = item;
            heap(maxElements);
        }
        System.out.println(maxElements[0] * maxElements[1] * maxElements[2]);
    }
    return k;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());    // no. of elements
    String line = br.readLine(); //accepting those elements in a string
    int[] maxElements = new int[3];
    int k = 0;
    int item = 0;
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        c = line.charAt(i);
        if (c == ' ') {
            k = addElement(k, maxElements, item);
            item = 0;
        } else {
            item = item * 10 + (c - '0');
        }
    }
    addElement(k, maxElements, item);
}
```

Comment: The solution is correct, but the runtime is still an issue here. Can it be further optimized? One of the test cases took 1.9001 secs in my program, whereas 1.6531 sec in yours. I want it to be within 1.0000 sec

Comment: @kamal0808 Your algorithm is O(n^2) and mine is O(n), you must try with a longest n, as 100000.. You'll see the difference!, If you want improve a little bit, I can replace a priorityQueue for an array. The largest time is losing in print the output

Comment: The runtimes i mentioned is with the longest inputs i.e. 100000. This here is a test case. I don't know if you can access this link https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/code-monk-heaps-and-priority-queues/problems/monk-and-multiplication/db311dc8-3-input-db311a2.txt?Signature=%2FxQRVxz0bVfYmihrInCC0o%2FqxvA%3D&Expires=1437596275&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ

Comment: @kamal0808 Edited, now it is little bit faster.

Comment: The runtime for 100000 is still 1.6598 sec. I wonder if it could at all be possible under 1 sec

Comment: @kamal0808 Edited again, It's little faster than the last version

Comment: As much as I appreciate you optimizing the code, it still goes over 1s according to this website. https://www.hackerearth.com/code-monk-heaps-and-priority-queues/algorithm/monk-and-multiplication/

Comment: Also, item variable is not initialized in your updated code

Answer (score 0):

The following solution removed all "number of elements" check code as it's not really necessary for the solution.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MonkMulti
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Input a list of numbers separated by space");
        String xs = br.readLine(); // accepting those elements in a string

        // split input values by space
        String[] numbers = xs.split("\\ ");
        // create int array
        int[] x = new int[numbers.length];
        // convert all strings to int
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            x[i] = Integer.valueOf(numbers[i]);
        }

        for (int arraySize = 3; arraySize <= x.length; arraySize++)
        {
            calculateMonkMulti(x, arraySize);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the product for different sizes
     * 
     * @param values
     * @param arraySize
     */
    private static void calculateMonkMulti(int[] values, int arraySize)
    {
        // new target sub array
        int[] sorted = new int[arraySize];
        // copy values of the sub array
        System.arraycopy(values, 0, sorted, 0, arraySize);
        // sort the sub array
        Arrays.sort(sorted);

        // calculate start index of top 3 elements
        int startIndex = sorted.length - 3;
        // get top three elements
        System.err.println(startIndex + "/" + arraySize + "/" + sorted.length);
        int int1 = sorted[startIndex];
        int int2 = sorted[++startIndex];
        int int3 = sorted[++startIndex];
        // calculate
        long result = int1 * int2 * int3;
        // output (or return)
        System.out.println(int1 + " * " + int2 + " * " + int3 + " = " + result);
    }
}
```

Solution using JDK classes and functions.

I get the following runtime values:
For the total array with 100.000 values from the link: Runtime: 47 ms for all sub arrays 100000 elements

For a runtime over all sub array of x elements, starting the following (updated after finished):

- Total runtime: 66 ms after 1000 elements with 100000 elements total
- Total runtime: 195 ms after 2000 elements with 100000 elements total
- Total runtime: 317 ms after 3000 elements with 100000 elements total
- ...
- Total runtime: 295667 ms after 98000 elements with 100000 elements total
- Total runtime: 301906 ms after 99000 elements with 100000 elements total
- Total runtime: 308266 ms after 100000 elements with 100000 elements total

Runtime: 308266 ms for all sub arrays 100000 elements

I do not know what the web site measures. The compilation time?

Version 2:
A new optimized version can solve the problem in total `Runtime: 26900 ms for all sub arrays 100000 elements`

And now Version 3:

- ...
- Total runtime: 54 ms after 98000 elements with 100000 elements total
- Total runtime: 54 ms after 99000 elements with 100000 elements total
- Total runtime: 54 ms after 100000 elements with 100000 elements total

Runtime: 55 ms for all sub arrays 100000 elements

My fastest solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MonkMulti
{
    static int[] sortedFast;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "u:/temp/numbers.txt")));
        String xs = br.readLine(); // accepting those elements in a string

        // split input values by space
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String[] numbers = xs.split("\\ ");
        // create int array
        int[] sourceValues = new int[numbers.length];
        // convert all strings to int
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            sourceValues[i] = Integer.valueOf(numbers[i]);
        }

        // create memory array for top 3 values
        sortedFast = new int[3];
        // copy first to elements from source to memory by one position up
        System.arraycopy(sourceValues, 0, sortedFast, 1, 2);
        // and set the lowest element to -1
        sortedFast[0] = -1;

        long result = 0;
        // start with 3 elements in sub array
        int startIndex = 3;
        // loop all sub arrays from 3 .. sourceValues.leength
        for (int arraySize = startIndex; arraySize <= sourceValues.length; arraySize++)
        {
            // calculate the value
            result += calculateMonkMegaFast(sourceValues, arraySize);
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out
                .println("Runtime: " + (endTime - startTime)
                        + " ms for all sub arrays " + sourceValues.length
                        + " elements (some value to ignore to prevent optimization: " + result + ")");
    }


    private final static long calculateMonkMegaFast(int[] values, int arraySize)
    {
        // check if the next element if greater as the lowest element in memory
        // sort the sub array
        if (values[arraySize - 1] > sortedFast[0])
        {
            // yes, replace lowest element with the bigger element from source
            sortedFast[0] = values[arraySize - 1];
            // sort the 3 element memory array
            Arrays.sort(sortedFast);
        }

        // get new top 3 elements
        int int1 = sortedFast[0];
        int int2 = sortedFast[1];
        int int3 = sortedFast[2];

        // calculate result
        long result = int1 * int2 * int3;
        // output (or return)
        // System.out.println(int1 + " * " + int2 + " * " + int3 + " = " +
        // result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Result calculation should use double to prevent value overflow. The complexity is almost O(n).

Comment: Correct solution. But the runtime for an input of 100000 elements is 1.6653 sec as compared to my original 1.9001 sec. How can this be further optimized to run within 1.0000 sec

Comment: You have nearly the same time for all solutions? How does you measure the time?

Comment: It is one of the problems from hackerearth.com. The runtime is measured by their compilation engines.

Comment: EarthHacker runtime is now 0.7241 sec with slightly changes to match the conditions.

Comment: As much as I appreciate you optimizing the code, it still goes over 1s according to this website. https://www.hackerearth.com/code-monk-heaps-and-priority-queues/algorithm/monk-and-multiplication/

Comment: And why use FileReader instead of InputStreamReader?

Comment: Simplify the local testing. This can simple adjusted to match the EarthHackers requirements. And should you solve the task from EarthHackers or would you use the postet solution? ;) Optimizing the output saves the time between the posted and the tested solution on earthhackers. I do not write the solution here for the moment. Try to find a way. ;)

Comment: @kamal0808 The result saving data type needs to be changed too.